# conflict between 2 bootstrap.css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded and customised a website template to fit my needs. The template came with a number of folders and files including js and bootstrap files.
Everything seems to work fine until I tried to integrate a php script which also happens to be designed and includes a number of js and bootstrap files.

I used firebug to debug the conflicts.

When I include the header and footer files together with the associated js and bootstrap files, the script loses most of the design (ie; the navigation panel).
I noticed that the **classes defined in the template bootstrap css files are the same as the ones in the scripts own bootstrap css file**.

How can i fix this?

Is there a way to exclude the main sites bootstrap files from affecting the installed script or vise-versa?

Comment: I recommend you to keep the bootstrap html/css/javascript files that worked for you, and remove all else. If you wish, you can add any new functionality to your existing files with new names.

Comment: Hi Sivatumma,Thanks for your reply. I am a little confused about what you mean here... the structure of my website is as follows public_html/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css (this is the file that came with the template) and the script is at public_html/folder/subfolder/script/theme/css/bootstrap.css (the file that came with the script) In the header is <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> and <link href="/folder/subfolder/script/theme/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">. I believe I need both for the website and the script to work properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used bootstrap and don't know much about it, but basically if you want to save the bootstrap styles just load them after your script.

Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/YOURCSS.css" />
<script src="js/YOURJS.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="js/bootstrapJS.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi NoSense,Thank you for your response, please see my comments in response to Sivatumma's reply. The problem is not including the files, it is actually the inheritance of classes within the various bootstrap files. Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Base on your comment I think that you load the script css after your main bootsrap css. Try to reverse their order or if that doesn't work - add your header to the question or as comment link to fiddle to inspect it.

Comment: Thank you NoSense, I will do so. I will try your suggestion as well as comment link to fiddle. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi NoSense,Please see below for the code sample link on fiddle. The first link is my original template file and associated header section (html) bootstrap.css (css), bootstrap.js (js)  website template on fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KNyU7/1/ - and the second is the php script header section (html) bootstrap.css (css) and the bootstrap.js file (javascript) php script on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qz3Gp/. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Could you add the html between <head></head> tag?

Comment: Hi NoSense, Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you be more specific??? What html and which head tags are you referring to??? Sorry for my ignorance and thanks again.

Comment: By "header" I mean mainly the whole section before the body tag where you define the css and js. Something like this - http://pastebin.com/EHAXAwrJ

Comment: Hi NoSense,Thank you for your patience and response. Is this what you meant? - http://pastebin.com/rad3TuQ4

Comment: I see that the reverse of the section didn't work...so...I haven't use bootstrap and don't have any other ideas but try to delete some stylesheets from the script section and see if that will work...if doesn't at a pinch you can try to add to every css rule of the main and custom stylesheets !important before end (I do not prefer it).

Comment: Hi NoSense, Thank you very much for your help and support. I hope someone can jump in and save the day, and hopefully save me a lot of recoding and insertions. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

These are the files you told you are including...

```
public_html/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
public_html/folder/subfolder/script/theme/css/bootstrap.css

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="/folder/subfolder/script/theme/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Two assumptions :

1. **Both the sets of files are the same in code.**
   Then, no problem, but it is not, from what you said.
2. **Both the sets are equal by name but different by content**. Then, if those files contain classes (or #id rules) of similar names, all the rules will be ordered in First come first read basis, and if there are multiple rules for a single property, the last rule for that property will be applied.

Example:

```
h1,h2, .heading, #heading{
font-family:georgia; /* from first file in the include order they are specified in html */
font-family:verdana; /* from second file */
font-family:arial; /* from third file */
},
```

then,

the last rule : `font-family:georgia; /* from the third file */` will be applied.

Debugging such things would be harder if you like to do. Because you can not guarantee the way how they get merged up. If all the code is written by yourself, you could have used a minifier like [this](http://cssminifier.com/) which removes all duplicates. But that is not the case.

Finally, you said *Everything seems to work fine until I tried to integrate a php script which also happens to be designed and includes a number of js and bootstrap files.*

Here, it is better to remove CSS classes that are similar in names **from the ones that came along with your php script folder.**

Comment: Hi Sivatumma,Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: Hi Sivatumma,Thank you for your response. You are right in your assessment of my situation, however, having done a lot of digging in the code to try and figure out what the issues are. The most prominent thing I have uncovered is the navigation menu. In my templtae, (using the booostrap.min.css, it uses the .navbar class defined in the bootstrap.css file. Also in the script header, the navigation uses the .navbar class. When I remove the .navbar class id in the scripts bootstrap.css file, it doesn't render the menu at all. This seems to be the case vise-versa. Hope I'm making myself clear.